# Java formatting a string from command line argument

Tags: java, string, formatting

I need help with formatting a string that gets passed in from the command line argument. So when I type

```
java Main "Tassimo T46 Home Brewing System|43-0439-6|17999|0.30:Moto Precise Fit Rear Wiper Blade|0210919|799|0.0: Easton Stealth Reflex Composite Hockey Stick| 83-4567-0|8999|0.5:Yardworks 4-Ton Log Splitter|60-3823-0|39999|0"
```

So it should be formatted displaying the name followed by several spaces then the **integers** followed by another few spaces then the second part of the **integers** then spaces followed by the **decimal**.

example

```
coffee      123456     199999     0.30
```

using String.format`.

Comment: are you replacing the | with spaces?

Comment: and isn't this question somehow related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21372450/java-splitting-command-line-argument ?

Comment: Try this one Use replaceAll("|", " ");

Comment: What's the logic that links the sample input to the sample output? The string "coffee" and most of those integer sequences don't appear in the input. Do you want a separate line for each product?

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695230/how-to-use-java-string-format), you only can do things like this using String.format:

```
String.format("%1$s %2$s %2$s %3$s", "a", "b", "c");
```

and the output:

```
a b b c
```

So I would recommend @praveen_mohan's answer. Use replaceAll method, or iterate over your_input.split("|") and build the output using StringBuilder.